# Why is this Solr query so slow?

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have ~250,000 documents indexed. Fetching 2 small fields from all documents takes about 2.5 minutes. **Why does it take so long and what can I do to speed it up?** To exlain what I'm doing: I'm syncing solr docs with MySQL records. The easiest way to do this (that handles deletes) is to compare everything in Solr to everything in MySQL.

http://localhost:8983/solr/[my collection]/select?q=*%3A*&fl=field1&fl=field2&rows=300000&wt=json

If I fetch it with curl, I can see it's writing the results at about 50KBps, which is way slower than a normal local http server document, so I know the issue must be internal to Solr. But why?

Surprisingly, the same query with a wt (writer type, aka response format) of CSV is just as slow. It seems the bottleneck is Solr itself.

I'm thinking it might be due to how I'm running Solr, which I believe is with default options. Here's the process from `ps`:

java -server -Xss256k -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:CMSFullGCsBeforeCompaction=1 -XX:CMSTriggerPermRatio=80 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/home/tylercollier/solr/dist/server/logs/solr_gc.log -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/home/tylercollier/solr/dist/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/home/tylercollier/solr/dist/server/solr -Dsolr.install.dir=/home/tylercollier/solr/dist -jar start.jar -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/home/tylercollier/solr/dist/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /home/tylercollier/solr/dist/server/logs --module=http

I am about to try messing with the memory sizes as described on [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/JVM+Settings). I still want to ask this question here first, because I typically find these 'guess and check' settings with memory frustrating to deal with, because it has a lot to do with the circumstances of the code and machine. But I'll report back with my findings.

**UPDATE**: Changing the Xmx value from 512m to 2g reduced the time from ~150 seconds down to ~50 seconds. But further increasing Xmx seems to make no difference (I've tried 3g, 4g). Changing Xss seems to make no difference. Its default is 256k, but I tried 1m and 5m. So, 50 seconds is an improvement on 150 s, but nowhere near what I want. MySQL can give me these results in 2 s or less. What gives?

**UPDATE 2**: Changing the query to return all fields (instead of limiting it to the 2 fields) makes no difference to the time either. This is really surprising to me. Now the CURL transfer rate is about 11 MB/s. I am incredulous that Solr can't pull its own records faster than that.

**UPDATE 3**: Has anyone else tried fetching so many documents from Solr at once (whether using paging or fetching all at once)? Is it as slow for you too?

Comment: i think if you only fetch alll data , you can read data mysql or use lucene , solr is not a  data warehouse ,  although you can do it.  may be you can try solr page to read all data , rows don't set too large

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using it at a data store. I'm using it for indexing it. In my scenario here, I'm trying to sync Solr with MySQL. My notes in the question discuss that row size isn't the bottleneck.

Comment: You can use pagination and fetch the data in chunks. That will be faster. If you don't need all the data at once.

Comment: I agree with the others, your problem is `rows=300000`. Just try it in a browser, use the exact query, but change rows to `rows=10` and expect a difference.

Comment: Another thought, why are you not doing it the other way around? Read data from MySQL (its good at this) and search for differences to Solr (Solr is good at searching).

Comment: I originally discovered this issue using paging with the node-solr-client library, using the default page size of 10 and using cursorMark. That took about 5 minutes or more, so fetching 300000 at once was a big improvement. I am trying to sync Solr and MySQL, so that's why I pull all all records/documents from each system. I loop over the MySQL records and see if they are already indexed by Solr.

Comment: I added a 3rd update.

Comment: Ahhh, there it comes. Let me guess, you had the problem as soon as you have been deep in the result set, right? We had this issue, they call it [Deep Paging](http://solr.pl/en/2011/07/18/deep-paging-problem/).

Comment: I wasn't doing deep paging. I had avoided that issue by using cursors, as they explain [on their wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results).

Comment: How large is the actual index on disk? The segments still have to be read and made available - enabling docValues for the field might help. I'd think a query as `*:*` would be more helpful as well (since iirc, that's the part shortcutted to "all documents"). In addition, if you're hitting 11MB/s in curl, that's strangely close to 100mbit - which shouldn't be an issue on localhost .. but ..

Comment: @MatsLindh the index is 660 MB on disk. The disk is SSD. As I said, I have tried a query with only 2 fields, as well as a query with all fields (*:*), it makes no difference. I am on localhost, so there's no 100 mbit limit.

Comment: Have you tried using the export request handler? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets - btw - my reference was to the actual query, not the `fl`.

Comment: @MatsLindh, that worked! It took approx 0 seconds with the export request handler. Please add that as an answer. I had to set up [docValues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues) to use the export. When I did that, I discovered that my fields, which were set up by someone else, were of type `string`, but `string`'s fieldType had been defined as solr.TextField. This means it wasn't able to be used for docValues until I switched it to solr.StrField. I was hoping that that change might allow a faster regular (non-export) select/query, but, alas, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dedicated request handler just for that purpose, the [Export Request Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Exporting+Result+Sets).

If you need to retrieve the complete query set, that's probably a better solution.

There's also [Streaming API support](http://heliosearch.org/streaming-aggregation-for-solrcloud/) in recent versions of Solr which might be suitable if you need to retrieve a large result set and process it while it's being retrieved, without having to allocate memory for the complete set at once. But this is limited to fields that supports DocValues, so it might not be suitable in this case (as your last comment indicates).